# Select where value could be null or actual valuein a trigger

Tags: select, sqlite, null, case

For example

```
TypeID = Select ID
         From Types
         Where Type = new.Type
```

new.Type could be a value or could possibly be null, currently if it is null it won't find the match, otherwise it does.

I tried

```
TypeID = Select ID
         From Types
         Where
              CASE
                  When new.Type is null Then Type Is Null
                  When new.Type is Not Null Then Type = new.Type
              END
```

but it gives me a syntax error near CASE.

I was thinking I could do

```
TypeID = Select ID
         From Types
         Where Type = new.Type OR Type IS Null
```

But this would return unwanted results in a few cases, like when new.Type is not in Types table I want it to return an error and NOT return the ID of Null.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite, the `IS` operator can also compare 'normal' values, so just write:

```
TypeID = Select ID
         From Types
         Where Type IS new.Type
```